# Making a Smooth Oval

Tags: modeling, mesh

So i'm super new to Blender and modelling etc, i'm trying to make an oval race track but want it to be completely smooth. I know how to get the shape of the track and can get the flat oval fine there's no bumps but then when i add the camber/tilt to the oval banking it's just a horrible bumpy mess no matter what resolution I use when converting it from a curve to a mesh. Any help for a newbie? Thanks.

Comment: hello, some pictures would help, or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Could you provide some pictures of your setting to help people understand what you ask?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to construct your track as a curve, and adjust the camber *before* converting it to a mesh.

Create 2 curves, one your track path, and another for the road surface. In the path, make sure there are control points at the apex of curves you wil need to camber.

[image]

In the path's Data tab, you can adjust assign the road surface as the path's Bevel Object, and the U resolution to give you reasonably smooth curvature (you might want to leave yourself room in the resolution for subdivision,later)

[image]

Under proportional editing, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> adjust the tilt of the curve at the points you want cambered. You can even <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> adjust the width of the track in places, if you want to.

[image]

When you're done, you can convert to a mesh, do whatever else you need to, and maybe subdivide for smoothness. Here, the perimeter has been extruded down in Z, for embedding in a landscape, but that would all depend on how you're constructing your scene.

I did find a bug while trialling this answer.. my curve was cyclic, and I had proportional editing set to 'Connected'. The Proportional Edit did not cross over the first-and-last control point on the curve, treating one side as if it was *not* connected. A get-around would be to split the curve, and rejoin it in a place that doesn't matter so much.

Comment: This is what I've done previously, I use the path tool when making the curve would you suggest perhaps using bezier?

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry, that's a bit ambiguous, I would definitely use a Bezier, here. The surface was made as a mesh-line, and converted to a curve. .. and I found a bug.. see edit.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a whirl and see what I can do. Using the path curve I can get everything I need like camber shape etc but the surface is just so bumpy no matter how many subdivisions I do

Comment: So I'm finding it a lot harder to work with the bezier curve for what I need to do. Do you know if there is anyway of achieving it just using the path curve I was using before without getting the horrific bumps in the corner? Image attached is what I'm aiming for https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/516QJHS19YL._SR600%2C315_PIWhiteStrip%2CBottomLeft%2C0%2C35_SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg

Comment: @JRob66 ..I think  it would help if you edited your Q. to include an image of the bumps you're referring to.

Comment: The bumps don't show in Blender whether you're in modelling,layout,sculpting etc mode only in game where you can feel them

Comment: @JRob66  Ahh! maybe make _that_ clear in your Q. My answer may be irrelevant. It may not be a Blender problem at all?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using curves (one curve for the oval and another rectangular curve for the track face--to use as a bevel for the oval) to create the track, and then convert the object to "mesh from curve."

Once you've got your evenly spaced mesh, you can use "proportional editing" the far right gizmo in the center top of your window to "lift" your cambers. Just make sure to "flat shade" your track or it'll look like a squashed snake.

[image]

Comment: So this is what i Have, before i wasn't using the solidify modifier but thought I'd give it a whirl as @SpikeSpiegel mentioned it, where would i go from here? https://gyazo.com/cd316879a8432bc8af0b8bc0f0224935

Comment: First, I'd get rid of the subdivision around the curves to make it easier to manipulate (select loop>dissolve edges. Then you can select the loops you want banked, have the proportional editor on while you try the shear tool, or just lift the outer edges [g]+[z].

Answer (score 0):

Definitely some pictures would help but it sounds like your mesh is lacking resolution. If your race track is just a plane, I would give it thickness with the solidify modifier, add support edges manually or with the bevel modifier and subdivide the mesh with the subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: This is what I have so far I've never used the solidify modifier but thought I'd give it a try as you suggested. Obviously the edges are still rough not smooth but no matter how much I subdivide it or triangulate it it's always way too bumpy to drive on. https://gyazo.com/cd316879a8432bc8af0b8bc0f0224935